# Javascript not recognizing the path to template folder

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I am making a web application in spring boot. I am trying to create popup window after 2.5 seconds the index page loads. However the javascript is not recognizing the path and throwing a white-label error.

All my web pages are inside "src/resources/templates/Pages"

index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Master</title>
<link th:href="@{http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    sleep(2500);
  newwindow=window.open('Pages/Home.html','MaSTER','height=800,width=1350');
    if (window.focus) {
        newwindow.focus()
    }
    return false;
}
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $("#footer").load("Master/Pages/Footer.html"); 
    });
});
</script-->
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div th:text="${message}+' Application'"></div>
<div id="footer" th:insert="Pages/Indexfooter.html"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:-

```
package com.ems.master.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MasterController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("message", "Master Manager");
        return "Pages/index.html";
    }

}
```

The error I am getting:-

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Aug 29 21:13:23 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Please suggest me what to?